# Protect dynamically allocated arrays

Tags: c, constants

I want to fill in a dynamically created array once only at the top of my function. Then every function after can only access the contents but not modify it. What is the correct way:

```
const double *pt = malloc(sizeof(double)*num);
```

OR

```
double *pt = malloc(sizeof(double)*num);
void f(const double array[], ...);
```

When I use the second method, do I have to cast *pt* to const?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method will not work because you won't be able to populate the array in the first place (since you have declared it `const`).

The second method will work if you have already populated the array *before* calling `f()`.

Comment: And you don't need a cast to add 'const'.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You mean when I call function f, I can simply pass pt to it without casting it to (const double*) first?

Comment: Correct. Adding 'const' is a trivial conversion. (Removing it, of course, is not!)

Answer (score 0):

Possible solutions:

1. Create a 'get' function that takes in an index and returns the value at the array, like this:

   ```
   double get(int index){
       return pt[index];
   }
   ```

   Make `get` publicly available but not `pt`.
2. Populate `pt` but keep it private and instead make available a 'const' pointer like this:

   ```
   //kept private:
   double * pt = malloc(...);
   pt[0] = 1;
   pt[1] = 2;
   ....

   //make public
   double const * public_pt = (double const *)pt;
   ```

Comment: Is there a way to make things private or public in C? NOT C++?

Comment: @Rich: Yes - you can do this using header/source files. Put the definitions for all functions/variables in your source (.c) file, but in the header file (that other people include) only declare the functions you want other people to be able to access.